# How to work with and how to parse a text file with mixed content in Java

Tags: java, parsing, text-files

I need some advice on how to go about processing a text file in Java. I have a file, where I have some lines on top with some data, and then a table. For example, in the beginning of the file I have totals like:

```
Cars purchased = 1890
Cars returned = 130
```

Then there is a table, which contains car ids:

```
id#1 =127974
id#2 =212445
```

And then another table:

```
table begin:

Customer ID | Price paid | Car brand#1 | Car brand#2 |  Car brand#4  
id#1
id#2
```

I have to

1. print out the cars purchased value, cars returned value, then an array with car ids and
2. create a tabular set based on the last table.

Can anyone please explain to me the logic on how to go about this in java? **I am not asking for a code, but for some guidelines/steps/pseudocode**. I can't understand how can I separate this text file into 3 chunks and have the input reader concentrate only on one of the three at a time. For example, the car ids can be similar to client ids in the table, so what can one do to not let the input reader read unnecessary information?

Another thing - if I read the file, where **parts of it are tab-separated and other parts are not**, how do I figure out where to begin reading the tab-separated part only?

If the beginning of the file has `Cars purchased = 1890` and i have to return 1890 only, do i have to scan through the entire file? Do I search for the words "Cars purchased" and then somehow access the value?

Then, when I have to put all of this back together in a tabular set, how do I know that each entry will match its relevant entry from the original file?

Also, this is not for working with a single file, but with whatever file of the same type provided, assuming that the key names like `Car id`, `Cars purchased`, `Cars returned` are the same.

I really need help with understanding how one would process a file like this.

Comment: Is there anything that clearly separates the sections, like that `table begin:`? If there is, you could define different handlers/parsers and switch to the required one as you read the lines. Something along the lines of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: you need to maintain a coloumn for returned/purchased in the table so that you can tract which model is purchased or returned and get data accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I can't understand how can I separate this text file into 3 chunks and have the input reader concentrate only on one of the three at a time."

Because you don't know where your data starts and stops, you need to read the text file sequentially, and only start paying attention to your data when you get to the section you want. In pseudocode:

```
while (you haven't gotten to the text that marks the start of a section) {
  read a line;
  throw the line away;
}
while (you haven't reached the text that marks the end of a section) {
  read a line;
  do something with the line;
}
```

You'll notice that after we're done with our section, we don't keep reading -- there's no need, unless there's something you want further on down.

Should you read in the whole thing and store it, or read it multiple times as you deal with each section? That's a design decision, based on lots of factors -- speed of reading, how much memory you have vs how much the data will take up, etc.

How do you know each entry will match the tabular data? That depends on how you store it. Read up a bit on objects and data structures for some ideas. For beginners, arrays are often easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like: you are trying to parse data from a text document to a table of data. I recommend try using an XML format instead and use either the Java native XML parser (which sucks imo), or a third party one to get the information. By using XML tags you can easily search for the car by ID and get attributes such as price brand etcetc...

It will be much easier to edit and view info for your cars... Here is an example:

```
<cars_purchased='10485'>
<cars_returned='1945'>

<cars>
    <id = '1000'>
         <brand>ASDF</brand>
         <car_model>SOMECARNAME</car_model>
         <price>$10000</price_paid>
         .......... And so on...
    </id>
    ... More cars here....
</cars>

<client>
     <clientID ='1000'>
          <client_paid>18424</client_paid>
          Whatever info u wanted on the client can go in tags here...
     </clientID>
     Any other clients....
</client>
```

From there using Java it is really simple to parse data from this xml, just go down by ID and you can get whatever info you want from the car to save to local variables...

So in order to find for example cars purchased, just look for that tag and it will return back with the value, you won't need to search through the entire file. Same thing would apply for anything else. Looking for a car? Just look under the cars chunk for the car_id... Looking for clients only? Look only at the clients chunk and search through for the correct ID...

For more on XML files look here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML...

Here to learn about how to use Javas native XML managing ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/index.html

Sorry for not using proper hyperlinking I'm on my phone and don't know how to do it manually...

Hopefully after reading the tutorials you can design a parser for yourself and edit/read the XML file with ease...

Comment: Yes, i would use XML, because it makes much more sense, but unfortunately I need to read them from the source without editing in the middle.

Comment: What do you mean 'read them from the source eithout editing in the middle'

Comment: I mean i am not supposed to convert the files to XML in order to parse them.

Comment: So you have to keep them as a text file and parse them that way? Are you allowed to edit the text file at all?

Comment: no, can't edit it at all, since there can be many files of the same sort, each of which will have to be parsed. I have to keep the file as is.